# Calculating the limit $|x|^{1/x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to calculate the limit

$$\lim _{x \to 0} |x|^{\frac 1 {x^2}}$$

I'm trying to do so without series expansions and l'hopital rule.

Comment: May be, you could take the logarithm

Answer (score 3):

hint: $e^{\frac{\ln|x|}{x^2}}$

Comment: Its not clear how you could evaluate $\ln |x|/x^2$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ without series expansions or l'hopital to me.

Comment: you must do case work e.g. $x>0$ or $x<0$

Comment: @1234, $\text{ln}|x| \rightarrow -\infty$ and $x^2 \rightarrow 0$, as $x \rightarrow 0$.